# Help regarding shadow/ reflection

Tags: light, lighting

I had posted here earlier and received some useful tips. However, I have one concern that is still bothering me.

[image]

The shadow on this phase seems to be going from light to dark to light, along with a streak/ line of pink. Ideally, I would like this entire phase to be uniform or a gradual gradient. Maybe something like this:

[image]

*is this the reflection from the sphere at the top and the plane down below? if so, how can i remove these reflections from interfering in the shadows. Could this be something completely different? I've kept the roughness of both the shapes quite high.*

My new setup is:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Both of your lights are very close to the ground. Try moving them up a bit, especially the point light.

You should also add a light on the other side of your object shining on the shadows. This light should be much softer and would soften up the shadows so they don't look so harsh.

There are lots of tutorials to help you with lighting out there. It might seem simple, but good lighting is much more complicated than you would imagine.

Comment: Thank you for your response! When I increase the height of the point light (i'm assuming this is the one closer to the shapes, since they are both area lights i believe), the light leaks to the face that I want in shadow.

Also my concern with the 3rd light is that it makes the shadow less harsh but it still doesnt even it out. thank you for the tip on checking on tutorials, I'm going to do that.